# How to display multiple live filters at once like iOS 7 Camera App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In the iOS 7 camera app, if you click on the icon in the bottom right corner it opens a collection view that is a 3x3 grid showing a live preview of different filters. How can this be recreated for our own app purposes? I have tried using GPUImage but I am only able to display one GPUImageView at a time and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you maybe show some code, for example on how you are trying to show multiple GPUImageViews? This way we know what you are trying to do and can help better.

Comment: The second after I posted this, I realized there is an example project in GPUImage that shows a multi-view live filters. I will look at that for now and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

GPUImage comes with a MultiViewImage example that fulfills this exact requirement. I will use it as a starting point.

The example was found in the GPUImage GitHub (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) under the directory /examples/iOS/MultiViewFilterExample/

[Direct Link](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/iOS/MultiViewFilterExample)

The project in that folder shows how to display 4 GPUImageViews, each with their own filter on one UIView.

Comment: Maybe you can link to where you found this?